# Passing JSON request starting with the character [ gives the error: invalid request format with GET operation

Tags: request, karate

When I pass a JSON request starting with `[`, I get the error which says: invalid request format with GET operation.

Here is my request. The same works fine in PostMan.

```
[
  {
    "equipmentNumber": "76576",
    "systemIdentifier": "00045F063547",
    "serialNumber": "00098",
    "materialNumber": "786786"
  }
]
```

Comment: please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

Your question is incomplete. Anyway I'll give it a shot. Here is a test that works perfectly fine in Karate, cut and paste it into a new `Scenario` and see for yourself.

```
* url 'https://httpbin.org/post'
* request 
"""
[
  {
    "equipmentNumber": "76576",
    "systemIdentifier": "00045F063547",
    "serialNumber": "00098",
    "materialNumber": "786786"
  }
]
"""
* method post
```

Which results in this request:

```
1 > POST https://httpbin.org/post
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > Content-Length: 112
1 > Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
1 > Host: httpbin.org
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/1.8.0_231)
[{"equipmentNumber":"76576","systemIdentifier":"00045F063547","serialNumber":"00098","materialNumber":"786786"}]
```

So if you are still stuck, follow this process - else no one can help you with the lack of information in your question: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: This didnt work. I need it in GET Method, its not working in GET method. error is cannot convert to map. This is the error: cannot convert to map: [{"equipmentNumber": "76576","systemIdentifier": "00045F063547","serialNumber": "00098","materialNumber": "786786"}]

Comment: @BhargavaMandya you can't use a `request` body for a GET, it is against the spec: https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/143475 - Karate will never support it - so either change your server side code or use Postman itself or another tool. If you want to do a "negative test" please don't do it for such cases, it is a waste of time

Comment: No, this is a positive use case. i am trying with params and its failing with error cannot convert to map: [{"equipmentNumber": "76576","systemIdentifier": "00045F063547","serialNumber": "00098","materialNumber": "786786"}]

Comment: @BhargavaMandya I have nothing else to add. Your question is incomplete. Maybe you mean `param` - but who knows: https://github.com/intuit/karate#param -  maybe someone else has the patience to help you - else follow the instructions in my answer

Comment: I have a request and i am trying the GET Operation from karate and when i do so with the request, the request body comes as null. So there is no way we can do get operation with request body in karate? This is my request [{"equipmentNumber": "76576","systemIdentifier": "00045F063547","serialNumber": "00098","materialNumber": "786786"}]